# Get the value printed on top of bar chart using python and matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to print the plot with the value on top of the bar which will change auto based on the graph. I am using the below code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
hsif = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\ans\\Desktop\\test.xlsx')
class_sum = hsif.groupby('Class')['Value'].sum()
class_sum_sort = class_sum.sort_values(ascending=False)
ax = class_sum_sort.plot.barh(x='Class',y=class_sum_sort).invert_yaxis()
plt.title('My Dynamic Graphs')
plt.xlabel('Value',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Class',fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

With the excel file consisting of the data as:

```
+----------+---------+
| Class    |  Value  |
+----------+---------+
|   Six    |  3763   |
|   Six    |  2570   |
|   Six    |  1123   |
|   Six    |  901    |
|   Seven  |  12210  |
|   Seven  |  10384  |
|   Seven  |  3188   |
|   Seven  |  2592   |
|   Seven  |  1723   |
|   Seven  |  1011   |
+----------+---------+
```

Can we add colour specific to `Six` as orange and `Seven` as red colour?
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the plot with the value on top of the bar which will change auto based on the graph"

Comment: Do you mean **on top** of each horizontal bar using `plot.barh( )` ?  
Do you mean from *which will change auto based on the graph*  is `autolabel` mechanism?

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the bars and set text and color.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hsif = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\ans\\Desktop\\test.xlsx')
class_sum = hsif.groupby('Class')['Value'].sum()
class_sum_sort = class_sum.sort_values(ascending=False)
ax = class_sum_sort.plot(kind="barh", fontsize=13)
ax.set_title('My Dynamic Graphs')
ax.set_xlabel('Value', fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Class', fontsize=20)    

for i in ax.patches:
    ax.text(i.get_width(), i.get_y()+.3, str(i.get_width()), fontsize=13)

ax.patches[0].set_color("red")
ax.patches[1].set_color("orange")

ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Probably OP means label the value on top of h bars not annotate in the right side of the end of the edge of bars.